# How can I move item from end of list to the start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3f;

    private GameObject[] objectstoMove;
    private List<GameObject> objectsMoving = new List<GameObject>();
    private float distanceTravelled = 0;
    private Vector3 lastPosition;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Init()
    {
        objectstoMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Test");
        objectsMoving = new List<GameObject>(objectstoMove);
        lastPosition = objectstoMove[objectstoMove.Length].transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (objectstoMove != null)
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            for (int i = 0; i < objectstoMove.Length; i++)
            {
                if(distanceTravelled >= 50.0f)
                {
                    objectsMoving.Remove(objectsMoving[objectsMoving.Count]);
                }

                objectsMoving[i].transform.Translate((objectsMoving[i].transform.up + objectsMoving[i].transform.forward) * step);

                distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance(objectsMoving[objectsMoving.Count].transform.position, lastPosition);
                lastPosition = objectsMoving[objectsMoving.Count].transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this part I want to take the last object in the list and move it to the start of the list:

```
if(distanceTravelled >= 50.0f)
                    {
                        objectsMoving.Remove(objectsMoving[objectsMoving.Count]);
                    }
```

The idea in general is to move the last item object from the list to the start of the list and keep moving the objects all the time but each time the last object in the list is distanceTravelled >= 50.0f move it to the start of the list. Same idea as cyclic if I'm not wrong.

Comment: `objectsMoving.Count` is out of range. You need a -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
if(distanceTravelled >= 50.0f)
{
    var moveToFirst = objectsMoving.Last();
    objectsMoving.RemoveAt(objectsMoving.Count-1);
    objectsMoving.Insert(0, moveToFirst);
}
```

Comment: Why not `.Remove(moveToFirst)`? Or alternatively, `moveToFirst = objectsMoving[objectsMoving.Count-1]`

Comment: @Draco18s `.Remove` will remove the *first* instance of the specified value. So if there's a duplicate, you're not removing the item at the last index. Probably not an issue in this case (though it could be), but something to be aware of.

Comment: If you swapped the order of operations, you could do it in one less line: `objectsMoving.Insert(0, objectsMoving.Last()); objectsMoving.RemoveAt(objectsMoving.Count-1);`